# Beacon scanning without location permission in android 6.0

Tags: android, bluetooth, ibeacon, beacon, android-ibeacon

Hi all am developing beacon based android application, it is works fine in below Android 6.0, it needs only the bluetooth permission. But Android 6.0 and above it's ask to give the bluetooth and also location permission.

**Why we need to give location permission for scanning beacons in Android 6.0?**

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am actually in the process of developing something similar and that amazes me too because logically you do not need location permissions  for scanning beacons via Bluetooth / low energy. This actually holds true for pre Android 6.0 - but Google decided to change that.

[From the notes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html):

> Access to Hardware Identifier
>   To provide users with greater data protection, starting in this release, Android removes programmatic access to the device’s local hardware identifier for apps using the Wi-Fi and Bluetooth APIs. The WifiInfo.getMacAddress() and the BluetoothAdapter.getAddress() methods now return a constant value of 02:00:00:00:00:00.
>
> To access the hardware identifiers of nearby external devices via Bluetooth and Wi-Fi scans, your app must now have the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions:
>
> WifiManager.getScanResults()
>   BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND
>   BluetoothLeScanner.startScan()
>
> Note: **When a device running Android 6.0 (API level 23) initiates a background Wi-Fi or Bluetooth scan, the operation is visible to external devices as originating from a randomized MAC address**

This does not mean you have to turn on GPS, but rather the location mode for `Bluetooh / Battery Saving` look at the picture here

[image]

Comment: Any Solution for this?

Comment: @BossRustler Not as of now.

Answer (score 0):

I check my code which i did it long ago, no you only need bluetooth enabled. As i can see in my code.  please ignore the postNotification method, since that is not required.

```
private void initBluetooth() {
        // Check if device supports Bluetooth Low Energy.
        if (!beaconManager.hasBluetooth()) {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Device does not have Bluetooth Low Energy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        // If Bluetooth is not enabled, let user enable it.
        if (!beaconManager.isBluetoothEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, Constant.REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        } else {
            Log.v(this.getClass(), "---> bluetooth already is enabled");
            startService(new Intent(this, EstimoteService.class));
        }
    }
```

//EstimoteService class

```
public class EstimoteService extends Service implements BeaconManager.RangingListener, BeaconManager.MonitoringListener {
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 123;
    private static final Region ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS_REGION = new Region("regionId", null, null, null);
    private Beacon beaconFound;

    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private BeaconManager beaconManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        initResources();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);

        // Default values are 5s of scanning and 25s of waiting time to save CPU cycles.
        // In order for this demo to be more responsive and immediate we lower down those values.
        beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1), 0);
        beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceReady() {
                try {
                    beaconManager.startRanging(ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS_REGION);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });


        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    private void initResources() {
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);
        beaconManager.setRangingListener(this);
        beaconManager.setMonitoringListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, List<Beacon> beacons) {
        if (beaconFound == null) {
            // Get the first available beaconFound
            if (beacons.isEmpty())
                return;

            beaconFound = beacons.get(0);
            final Region beaconRegion = new Region("regionId", beaconFound.getProximityUUID(), beaconFound.getMajor(), beaconFound.getMinor());
            beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onServiceReady() {
                    try {
                        beaconManager.startMonitoring(beaconRegion);
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnteredRegion(Region region, List<Beacon> beacons) {
        postNotification("Entered region");
        System.out.println("---> enter region");
    }

    @Override
    public void onExitedRegion(Region region) {
        postNotification("Exited region");
        System.out.println("---> exit region");
    }

    private void postNotification(String msg) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.beacon_gray).setContentTitle("XXX").setContentText(msg);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: kggoh - For Android Marshmallow why we need give location permission for 6.0?